# Operations on state in computed property yields console error on component load

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I'm applying regular JavaScript functions (`split` and `join`) to a computed property which itself receives a state variable.

However I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"` error when component mounts because at that time my computed property `user` is temporarily still empty.

Any way around that?

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ userDob }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex"

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: state => state.dashboard.user || {}
    }),
    userDob() {
      return this.user.date_of_birth.split("-").reverse().join("-")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1

You can set default value for the object in Vuex so it always has something to work with:

```
user: {
  date_of_birth: "01-01-1970"
}
```

### Method 2

You can just display an empty string while it's getting the data:

```
userDob() {
  try {
    return this.user.date_of_birth.split("-").reverse().join("-")
  }
  catch(error) {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it does work technically but I'd like to find something shorter or more elegant than that

Comment: @drake035 yeah, it's unfortunate we don't have a better way to deal with it, well at least I couldn't find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `v-if` directive to the `div` element that includes the computed property.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="user">
    {{ userDob }}
  </div>
</template>
```

> The directive v-if is used to conditionally render a block. The block will only be rendered if the directive’s expression returns a truthy value.

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Truthy value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy